# Law of karma applies to monkeys also?

Tags: belief, gods, karma

Since we all know that man is evaluation from monkeys.

Previously all our anscestors were monkey.

So law of karma today, do gets applied to Monkeys also?

Comment: BTW, technically man is an evolution of ape like species not modern monkeys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Law of Karma applies only to the Humans. Now, you might think then how do monkeys get reborn in a different being without Karma affecting. The straight answer is that Humans are the only living beings to whom Karma is applied and when Humans don't have a good life to have Heaven(Badrikashram, Shwetdweep, Vaikunth, Golok, Akshardham-the ultimate dwelling from where no one gets rebirth in any form in earth or heaven. etc..) then that human gets rebirth in the form of any living creature( may be Human again or birds, animals, trees, insects, bacteria, etc.. which are 8400000 living creatures in all. The word used is "chorashi" meaning "Eighty Four" because there are 8400000 different types of living creatures in which he can get a birth). Also, according to "Vachanamrut" by Bhagwan Swaminarayan, He said that this isn't a first birth of yours, but we all have taken births in all the forms many a times till now and He also told that we all have drank enough milk of mother that is equal to the water in the oceans in this earth. Thus, Humans are given birth according to his Karma.

Shastriji Maharaj(Yagnapurush Das)-Spiritual Successor of Bhagwan Swaminarayan once told his devotee that,"This tree should be cut now because we need to give this aatma a birth in a human body." One of his devotee had no child so he told that,"This aatma will take birth in your family the next year." (explanation-That aatma had got birth in a Human body but his Karma made him birth into a tree)

Also present Spiritual successor of Bhagwan Swaminarayan, HDH Pramukh Swami Maharaj who is currently at Sarangpur, Gujarat(India) got a phone call many years back of his devotee from an outer country,"My son is unhealthy since long. Please help us." Pramukh Swami said,"Listen, your child will get well after few days, but will again get disease and then he will meet the death." Parents of that child got shocked after listening this and questioned why was He saying that thing! Pramukh Swami replied,"Your child is a "mumukshu jiv" (meaning-seeker of God who wants moksh only) of the last birth. So he is given a birth in Satsangi family to attain Moksh and God will take child to Akshardham."

This reveals that Karma applies to Humans and not other animals. After paying births in different bodies according to Karma, we get birth into Human body again to attian Moksh-which is a final stand.